# how to move my public key from my windows computer to a mac

Tags: key

I have been issued a mac and I want to use the same key that I used on my old windows computer so that I don't have to set my new keys on the places I connect to like git.

so I moved my public key ending in .pub to ~/.ssh in my mac.

but I still cannot connect to git as I can with my windows computer.
it says permission denied (public key)

what else do I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do this:

```sh
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa 
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```